# Cant get Log4j Database logging working

Tags: java, maven, logging, log4j

I'm trying to configure log4j database logging into a maven web project but cant get it working. Would appreciate if some one can point out what i'm doing wrong.

I'v created a maven web project and its deployed in jboss wildfly.

I've added these two dependencies.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.36</version>
    </dependency>
```

And i've added log4j.properties file under resources.

```
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, DB

log4j.appender.DB=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender

log4j.appender.DB.URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pos_test

log4j.appender.DB.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

log4j.appender.DB.user=root
log4j.appender.DB.password=password

log4j.appender.DB.sql=INSERT INTO myLogs VALUES('%X{User}','%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}','%C','%p','%m')

log4j.appender.DB.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

In my code i try to log as follows,

```
logger.info("Testing info");
logger.debug("Testing Debug");
```

I've used the following sql to create the database table.

```
CREATE TABLE myLogs (             
   USER_ID  varchar(20) NOT NULL,     
   LOG_DATE  date NOT NULL,           
   LOGGER  varchar(50) NOT NULL,      
   LEVEL  varchar(10) NOT NULL,       
   MESSAGE  varchar(1000) NOT NULL   
);
```

There are no errors in the log and also the logger information are not printed on the server log.

Still the logging info are not added to the database.

What am i missing here ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

To me **conceptually** you're doing everything right.

I don't know much about wildfly, but I would try to to the following:

1. Ensure that your whole logging configuration is deployed correctly.
   There are different ways of doing that:

   - Open your WAR/EAR with your favorite tool (winrar or something) and see whether the logging properties file really exists in the correct place (WEB-INF\classes in the case of WAR).
   - The same goes for log4j dependency - it should be packed correctly into the 'lib' folder
2. Try any different appender, say console appender or file appender. Just to ensure it works. Maybe even use both appenders simultaneously (log4j permits that)
3. Maybe you do have some errors but they're not intercepted by the logging system because the only appender you use is a db appender and something goes wrong with it.
4. Does you particular call to the logging system really causes the db appender to be called? The best way to ensure it would be debugging the log4j - it's not that hard, believe me, this one is pretty easy to understand :)

Hope this helps

Mark

Comment: Hi Mark Thanks for the reply. configuration file and the jar is in correct place. How ever i tried having multiple appenders but it didnt work. I tried having console and db appenders but the console didnt print the output.

Comment: I tried having the log4j.properties file only with a console appender. Still it doesnt work.

Comment: I think this means that somehow your configuration is not processed. The best way is to debug from here. Just step into the logging call and see, which appenders are actually used. Try to use root logger explicitly for debugging purposes... Maybe you're using spring or something? If its only a webapp and log4j, please read this article, it might help: http://www.codejava.net/coding/how-to-initialize-log4j-for-java-web-application

Comment: Hi Mark thanks for the info. I'm using a normal web application with log4j. but i'm not using any servlets. I have few classes that exposes a rest api using rest easy. Can this be the issue for log4j property file not being picked up ?